# Crop hash structure: Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, hashtable

I want to delete data from a hash table using a specific range of values.

Example:

`hash = { t:1, y:9, k:10, a:30, b:40, c:50, d:80, e:60, z:100, l:3, n:9, f:20 }`

Given an array of numbers: `array = [10, 30, 40, 50, 80, 60, 100]` (is exactly the range of the center of the table)

I want the result to be:

`hash: {k:10, a:30, b:40, c:50, d:80, e:60, z:100}`

Notes that never eliminated data that is in the middle of the structure.

Answer (score 7):

Look at the [`select` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-select).

```
[6] pry(main)> hash.select { |k,v| array.include?(v) }
=> {:k=>10, :a=>30, :b=>40, :c=>50, :d=>80, :e=>60, :z=>100}
```

Comment: What if I have repeated values​​? Like `{50, 50, 30, 32}`

Comment: If you have repeated values in the array it will work fine, the `include?` will still be true when asked.  If you have repeated values in the hash, they will be selected and kept in the hash.

Answer (score 1):

```
results = {}
hash.each { |k, v| results[k] = v if array.include?(v) }
puts results
```

output:

```
{:k=>10, :a=>30, :b=>40, :c=>50, :d=>80, :e=>60, :z=>100}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.each_with_object({}){|e, h| h[hash.key(e)] = e if hash.value?(e)}
```